# Late run time binding with respect to intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried going through the developer forum for intents. And i did not understand much from it. 
Especially these lines.

“Activities in Android are activated through messages called intents. Intent messaging is a facility for late run-time binding between components in the same or different applications. The intent itself, an Intent object, is a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an operation to be performed.”

I have a few questions regarding this.

> (a)Why is the intent messaging facility considered as a late run-time
>   binding between components?
>
> (b)Why is the word “passive” used for the intent data structure?
>
> (c) Can anybody give me with an example what this abstract description
>   of an operation to be performed means ?

Answer (score 6):

> Why is the intent messaging facility considered as a late run-time binding between components?

Because it is not a compile-time binding between components (e.g., using Java constructors).

> Why is the word “passive” used for the intent data structure?

Because `Intents` are messages, ones that do not *do* work themselves but rather indicate work that something else is to do.

> Can anybody give me with an example what this abstract description of an operation to be performed means ?

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://commonsware.com")));
```

Here, the `Intent` is an abstract description: we want to "view" something that is identified by a URI that begins with `http://`. On Android, any number of activities could respond to this `Intent`, including Web browsers and dedicated apps by balding guys in support of their Web site. Depending on device, zero, one, or several activities could match this `Intent` structure, and Android can handle all of those scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

> (a)Why is the intent messaging facility considered as a late run-time binding between components?

I would assume this is because, while you can set `intent filters` in the `manifest`, they are often used in the Java code to start new `Activities` during run time and pass data between `Activities`.

> (b)Why is the word “passive” used for the intent data structure?

An `Intent` isn't actually an action but, as it says, a message telling a component what to do and giving it data.

> Can anybody give me with an example what this abstract description of an operation to be performed means ?

In its simplest and most common form an `Intent` is used like this to start an `Activity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent. putExtra("key", value);  // used to send data such as a variable value. "key" is used in NextActivity to retrieve the data, value is the actual variable that you want to send
startActivity(intent);  //starts the NextActivity
```

I hope this answers your questions.